# dynamic action on a table tDBOutput component

Tags: database, talend

My question is :

Is it possible to specify the action(Truncate table / Delete table if not existe ..) on a tDBOutput dynamically with a variable context ?

**The purpose of this job is :**

- to register a new mode_exec context variable at the job level to configure the execution mode .
- `mode_exec = INIT` (initialization) allowing to make a truncate of a DW table before being loaded by a data file.
- `mode_exec = INCR` (incremental) forbidding to make a truncate of a DW table before it is loaded by a data file.

Any explication plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you won't be able to do this kind of operations in a tDBOutput.
But you can set up a tDBRow with instruction "Truncate TABLE XX" at the beginning of your job. 
Then you condition the execution of this tDBRow component with your variable, in an "IF" link" :

[image]

In the IF link you'll have the condition `"INIT".equals(context.mode_exec)`

This should work, let me know.